# Using dbup in concurrent environment

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, dbup

We have multiple binaries/processes that references the same backend database for load-balancing, went through the documentation but didn't find much information on any best practices for updating database in concurrent environment.

Does anyone have experienced such issues in production environment?